# How can I colour / fill up an arc surface in 2D animation

Tags: 2d

I was using arc in draw mode to create a shape
[image: 3D View][image: numpad 3's view]
For now, I only know how to fill up a flat surface, but not for when I make an arc surface like this one:
[image: whenever I tried to fill up the arc one, it always become a rectangle shape][image: can the rectangle be bend?]